# How do I convert DateTime object to HTTP format?

Tags: perl, datetime

I'm using the DateTime Perl module to get the time in a particular timezone. The result of the time is as follows

> 2010-09-24T02:18:52

How can I convert this to HTTP format before printing?

Comment: can you clarify - do you have a time with timezone as input, and want time and different timezone as output?  Or is the input time GMT?

Comment: The HTTP standard requires that all date/time stamps MUST be in GMT.  If you want a different timezone, it's not really HTTP format.  It would be more accurate to say you want a [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) date, as updated by [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPAN has what you need: [DateTime::Format::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~ckras/DateTime-Format-HTTP-0.39/lib/DateTime/Format/HTTP.pm).

Description:

> This module provides functions that deal [with] the date formats used by the HTTP protocol (and then some more).

Synopsis:

```
use DateTime::Format::HTTP;

my $class = 'DateTime::Format::HTTP';
$string = $class->format_datetime($dt); # Format as GMT ASCII time
$time = $class->parse_datetime($string); # convert ASCII date to machine time
```

*Update*

You can pass in the timezone of your source data, use DateTime [set_time_zone()](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.62/lib/DateTime.pm#%22Set%22_Methods) to change the timezone, and then use
[strftime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.62/lib/DateTime.pm#strftime_Patterns) to generate the string in 'HTTP' format.  For example:

```
my $dt = DateTime::Format::HTTP->parse_datetime( '2010-03-09T12:34:56', 'EST' );
warn $class->format_datetime( $dt );
warn $dt->strftime( "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" );
$dt->set_time_zone( 'CET' );
warn $dt->strftime( "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z" );

Tue, 09 Mar 2010 17:34:56 GMT
Tue, 09 Mar 2010 12:34:56 EST
Tue, 09 Mar 2010 18:34:56 CET
```

*(line numbers deleted for clarity.)*

Comment: I've tried that. It converts everything to GMT. I want it in my timezone

Comment: @Powertieke, DateTime::Format::HTTP's `format_datetime` method does _not_ allow you to specify the timezone.  It always produces GMT, in accordance with [RFC 2616 section 3.3.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1): "All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), without exception."

Comment: You are right, I was looking at parse_datetime()... deleted my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @cjm - do you want to post a modified comment, or edit your note into the answer/add an answer for 'completeness'?